# How to set Label to use HTML tags on Graphviz4Net API

Tags: graphviz

I have the following codes:

The code generated by the API does not work:

```
digraph g {
 graph [rankdir="LR" ,nodesep="1" ,compound="true" ];
    subgraph cluster0 {
        graph [label="<TABLE><TR><TD>End</TD></TR></TABLE>" ,shape="plaintext" ];
        1 [ shape="none" ,fontcolor="white"  ];
    };
}
```

Changing the generated to this works:

```
digraph g {
 graph [rankdir="LR" ,nodesep="1" ,compound="true" ];
    subgraph cluster0 {
        graph [label=< <TABLE><TR><TD>End</TD></TR></TABLE> > ,shape="plaintext" ];
        1 [ shape="none" ,fontcolor="white"  ];
    };
}
```

The simple use of `Label=<` instead of `Label="` Makes it work.

I'm using the latest version of Graphviz API and am coding in C#. I add the label as below:

```
var newBlockSubgraph = new SubGraph<MyClass> { Label = stringBuilder.ToString()};
```

Is it possible to do the change in the generated code? I need the label to be `Label=<`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recompiled the [Graphviz4Net](http://graphviz4net.codeplex.com/) with the necessary changes. The official compiled version has not implemented and compiled the bug fix.

You can download the version I compiled [here](http://www.4shared.com/zip/vxdgCnKy/Graphviz4Net.html). **PS.:** Host removed file and i do not have it available atm.

It can now generate the code Label=<  in dot code

**Example of syntax**

```
var newBlockSubgraph = new SubGraph<State> { Label = "<<b>Hello World</b>>" };
```